# EA origin Game download problem

Tags: origin, titanfall

I bought Titanfall a couple of days ago. I am presently downloading the game. However, after every 5 or 6 hours or so, 3 - 4 Gb of downloaded data automatically vanishes. For example, I had downloaded 10 Gb of the game, and after couple of hours I checked, it was only 5 Gb remaining . This has been happeneing quite often now. To be honest, I have lost MORE data than actually Downloaded. And today 3 times in a row, I again lost around 2 GB every time when only 10 Mb of data was left for the game to complete downloading. Please help me. I am really pissed now.

(There is no way my internet is faulty).

(Also, my friend has titanfall DVD. Can I use it to install ? I have legally bought titanfall on origin)

Answer (score 1):

Going from generic IT experience, rather then personal experience with the PC version of the game or Origin, it's hard to say what the exact issue can be that is causing your data loss. It could be a whole range of issues. I'd recommend contacting EA support (I know, it's horrible) and see if they can help you, if nothing else helps.

However, your friend's DVD should work. The physical disc is not bound to any key or accounts. Once the game is installed, you'll login with your own Origin account and the game should recognize that you have a legit copy of Titanfall linked to your account, and it should let you play. It's certainly not against EA's policy or anything, so it's definitely worth a try!

Comment: All those stupid folks say eveytime is to check internet connection, uninstall origin and reinstall or delete entire game data and start over again. (Just imagine 20 gb over and over again)

Comment: :( I feel your pain, I hope it'll work from a physical disk.

Comment: I am broke :( . It happened 2 times again since posting this Q.

Comment: I'd also recommend right clicking the game and using the 'Verify install' or similar in the menu to allow your game to resume downloading.

Answer (score 0):

For the record,

Origin downloads work in a not so efficient way. Origin downloads big chunks of data, and once these chunks are downloaded they check the files consistency by a CRC check. If this check fails,(which for some reason fails a lot) the entire chunk is downloaded again. I had this problem last year when downloading BF3.

A kind of solution, (more like a workaround), is to keep a backup of the current game download, that is, pause it every certain time, copy the game files already downloaded to another location, and resume the donwload. If such download resets, you pause the download, close Origin, delete the current game files, restore them with you backup, launch Origin, and resume the download. By following these steps it will eventually end. I'd recommend to run a validation test once it's done, just in case. But remember, make another backup first.